# Max-Heap arraylist based priority queue written in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, queue

I have a program that I'm writing that needs to use a priority queue as part of an algorithm. I specifically need to order (String, Integer) pairs for example (Bread, 3), (Beer, 5), (Eggs,2), etc.

I'd appreciate any comments on my code style and how I've written my class.

```
import javafx.util.Pair;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;



public class FPPriorityQueue implements PriorityQueue {

private ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>> heapArray;

public FPPriorityQueue(){
    super();
    heapArray = new ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>>();
}

public boolean empty(){
    return true;
}

private Integer getParentData(int index){
    int parentIndex = index/2;
    Pair<String, Integer> parentData = heapArray.get(parentIndex);
    return parentData.getValue();
}

private void swap(Integer old, Integer knew){
    Collections.swap(heapArray,old,knew);

}

private void shiftUp(int index){

    int parentIndex;

    if(index != 1){
        parentIndex = index/2;
        int childData = heapArray.get(index).getValue();
        int parentData = getParentData(index);

        if(parentData < childData){
            swap(parentIndex,index);
            shiftUp(parentIndex);
        }
    }
}

private void shiftDown(int index){

    if(heapArray.size()> (index*2)+1) {
        int leftChildValue = heapArray.get(index * 2).getValue();
        int rightChildValue = heapArray.get((index * 2) + 1).getValue();

        int indexValue = heapArray.get(index).getValue();

        if(indexValue < leftChildValue || indexValue < rightChildValue)
        {
            if(leftChildValue > rightChildValue){
                int leftChildIndex = index*2;
                swap(index,leftChildIndex);
                shiftDown(leftChildIndex);
            }
            else{
                int rightChildIndex = (index*2)+1;
                swap(index,rightChildIndex);
                shiftDown(rightChildIndex);
            }
        }
    }

}

public void insert(String key, Integer value){

    Pair<String, Integer> element = new Pair<String, Integer>(key,value);
    Pair<String, Integer> nullElement = new Pair<String, Integer>("NULL",0);
    //add the element to the last position in the list
    if(heapArray.isEmpty()){
        heapArray.add(0,nullElement);
        heapArray.add(1,element);
    }
    else{
        heapArray.add(heapArray.size(), element);
        shiftUp(heapArray.size()-1);
    }

}

public Pair<String, Integer> removeMax(){

    Pair<String, Integer> returnValue = heapArray.remove(1);
    Collections.swap(heapArray,heapArray.size()-1,1);
    shiftDown(1);

    return returnValue;

}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Don't override with the default behavior

> ```
>     private ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>> heapArray;
>
>     public FPPriorityQueue(){
>         super();
>         heapArray = new ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>>();
>     }
> ```

This could be simply

```
    private List<Pair<String, Integer>> heap = new ArrayList<>();
```

You don't need a custom constructor.  This will declare and initialize it.

I prefer the name `heap` to `heapArray`.  It's simpler and more accurate.

In the latest Java, you don't have to specify `Pair<String, Integer>` twice.  It's smart enough to figure it out if you just say `<>`.

In general, it is preferable to use interfaces as types rather than implementations.  Among other reasons, it allows you to change implementations easily.

#### Huh?

> ```
> public boolean empty(){
>     return true;
> }
> ```

What's this do?  If it was called `isEmpty`, I'd think it was returning whether or not the heap was empty.  As is, I would expect `empty` to do something, perhaps clear the heap.

Whatever it's supposed to do, it doesn't seem to be doing it.

#### Don't rely on your inputs

> ```
> private void shiftUp(int index){
>
>     int parentIndex;
>
>     if(index != 1){
>         parentIndex = index/2;
>         int childData = heapArray.get(index).getValue();
>         int parentData = getParentData(index);
>
>         if(parentData < childData){
>             swap(parentIndex,index);
>             shiftUp(parentIndex);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

What if `index` is less than 1?

```
private void shiftUp(int index) {
    if (index > 1) {
        int parentIndex = index / 2;
        int parentData = heap.get(parentIndex).getValue();
        int childData = heap.get(index).getValue();

        if (parentData < childData) {
            swap(parentIndex, index);
            shiftUp(parentIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Changing `!=` to `>` handles `index` values less than 1.  And it's free.  We're already doing a comparison.  Why not do the better one?

We don't need `getParentData`.  We have to calculate `parentIndex` anyway, so we can just fetch directly.

I added some extra whitespace, because I find code easier to read that way.

#### Don't do unnecessary work

> ```
> public void insert(String key, Integer value){
>
>     Pair<String, Integer> element = new Pair<String, Integer>(key,value);
>     Pair<String, Integer> nullElement = new Pair<String, Integer>("NULL",0);
>     //add the element to the last position in the list
>     if(heapArray.isEmpty()){
>         heapArray.add(0,nullElement);
>         heapArray.add(1,element);
>     }
>     else{
>         heapArray.add(heapArray.size(), element);
>         shiftUp(heapArray.size()-1);
>     }
>
> }
> ```

We don't need `nullElement` every time.  Consider

```
public void insert(String key, Integer value) {
    Pair<String, Integer> element = new Pair<>(key,value);

    //add the element to the last position in the list
    if (heapArray.isEmpty()) {
        heap.add(new Pair<String, Integer>("NULL", 0));
        heap.add(element);
    } else {
        heap.add(element);
        shiftUp(heap.size()-1);
    }
}
```

We don't have to explicitly say that we want to put things in the last position.  That's how the single argument `add` works already.

I personally am not crazy about the half-cuddled `else {`, and it's not the Java standard.  So I fully cuddled:  `} else {`.

We only create `nullElement` in the one edge case now.  The rest of the time, we don't bother.  But we can actually do better.  Consider

```
public FPPriorityQueue() {
    heap.add(new Pair<String, Integer>("NULL", 0));
}
```

This will create the null element the one time you need it, at the beginning.  And this is the kind of thing that you do in a constructor.

You don't need the explicit `super()`.  Java's smart enough to do that for you when you're just calling the default constructor.

Now we can just say

```
    public void insert(String key, Integer value) {
       //add the element to the last position in the list
        heap.add(new Pair<String, Integer>(key, value));
        shiftUp(heap.size() - 1);
    }
```

It adds to the end of the list.

And because we previously changed `shiftUp` to handle the empty case, we don't need to prevent calling `shiftUp` in that case.

I'm not sure that we need the null element.  The math is a little more complex without it but still doable.

#### Don't Repeat Yourself

> ```
> private void shiftDown(int index){
>
>     if(heapArray.size()> (index*2)+1) {
>         int leftChildValue = heapArray.get(index * 2).getValue();
>         int rightChildValue = heapArray.get((index * 2) + 1).getValue();
>
>         int indexValue = heapArray.get(index).getValue();
>
>         if(indexValue < leftChildValue || indexValue < rightChildValue)
>         {
>             if(leftChildValue > rightChildValue){
>                 int leftChildIndex = index*2;
>                 swap(index,leftChildIndex);
>                 shiftDown(leftChildIndex);
>             }
>             else{
>                 int rightChildIndex = (index*2)+1;
>                 swap(index,rightChildIndex);
>                 shiftDown(rightChildIndex);
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Consider

```
private void shiftDown(int index) {
    int left = index * 2;
    int right = left + 1;
    if (heap.size() > right) {
        int leftChildValue = heap.get(left).getValue();
        int rightChildValue = heap.get(right).getValue();

        int indexValue = heap.get(index).getValue();

        if (indexValue < leftChildValue || indexValue < rightChildValue) {
            if (leftChildValue > rightChildValue) {
                swap(index, left);
                shiftDown(left);
            } else {
                swap(index, right);
                shiftDown(right);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way we set `left` and `right` before using them.  So we can't accidentally pick the wrong value one place.

#### Don't reinvent the wheel

If this is an exercise to improve your understanding of how a heap works, that's fine.  There's a reinvent-the-wheel tag that you can use to let us know.  But if you just needed to solve the problem, an easier way is to use a `PriorityQueue` with a custom `Comparator` or a custom type that `extends Comparable`.  Then Java will handle all the fiddly bits of managing the heap.

```
public class PairComparator implements Comparator<Pair<String, Integer>> {

    public int compare(Pair<String, Integer> a, Pair<String, Integer> b) {
        return b.getValue().compareTo(a.getValue());
    }

}
```

If the order is backwards, switch `a` and `b` in the `return` line.

I forget if you have to implement `equals` as well.

You'd use this like

```
        PriorityQueue<Pair<String, Integer>> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(new PairComparator());
```

Then you can call `queue.add` and `queue.poll` to insert and remove items.

You don't provide test code, so I haven't tried to compile and test any of this.  Beware of typos, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! You pointed out some things that I definitely didn't think about.